# Joining change log table to event table (SparkSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark-sql, subquery, presto

I have two tables that I need to join together

Table 1 is a change table (status_change)

```
| ID | VALUE | TIME  |
|----|-------|-------|
| X  | A     | 10:45 |
| X  | B     | 11:30 |
| X  | C     | 12:15 |
```

And table 2 is events (event_log)

```
| ID | TIME  | *** |
|----|-------|-----|
| X  | 11:35 | *** |
| X  | 12:20 | *** |
| X  | 12:30 | *** |
| X  | 12:50 | *** |
```

I would like to join these two table so that change value (A,B,C) is on my event table in the given time frame it is active i.e.

```
| ID | TIME  | VALUE | *** |
|----|-------|-------|-----|
| X  | 11:35 | A     | *** |
| X  | 12:20 | B     | *** |
| X  | 12:30 | B     | *** |
| X  | 12:50 | C     | *** |
```

I have tried doing joins but this gives me every possible change attached, I also tried adding in limits in the select and that did not work either

See code below of example:

```
select
  event_log.*,
  status_change.new_change
from
  event_log
  left join (
    select
      status_change.new_change,
      MIN(status_changes.id) as id,
      status_changes.time
    from
      status_changes
    group by
      1,
      3
    order by
      3 desc
  ) status_change on status_change.id = event_log.id
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If I understood correctly, your query logic should be as follows. with cte as(table1 left join table2) select * from cte where table1.time<table2.time

Comment: @s.voruganti is table1 the status table or the event table?